# ¿Por qué al realizar la función is.na(NULL) en R devuelve logical(0)?

Tags: r, function

Si en la consola de R escribimos el siguiente código:

```
is.na(NULL)
```

Nos devuelve:

```
logical(0)
```

¿Por qué devuelve este valor y no devuelve FALSE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hay que entender la sutil diferencia entre `NA` y `NULL`, Conceptualmente `NA` es: existe un dato pero no tenemos un valor válido, mientras que `NULL` es: no existe directamente el dato. Teniendo esto en mente, es más claro por que:

```
is.na(NULL) == logical(0)
```

Por defecto, `is.na` nos entrega un vector de lógicos consistente con la longitud del vector de entrada, al ser `NULL` es decir, no existir tal vector de entrada, es lógico que el retorno sea un vector `logical` sin elementos.

Por otro lado, esta es una decisión de diseño que está documentada en la ayuda de la función:

> anyNA(NULL) is false; is.na(NULL) is logical(0) (no longer warning
> since R version 3.5.0).

Una pregunta interesante es por que `is.numeric(NULL)` no retorna lo mismo que es `is.na(NULL)` o ¿por que parece inconsistente el comportamiento de las dos funciones?

Nuevamente hay una decisión de diseño que está documentada en la ayuda de `is.numeric()`:

> The default method for is.numeric returns TRUE if its argument is of
> mode "numeric"

Y ciertamente se verifica esto:

```
> mode(1)
[1] "numeric"
> mode(1.0)
[1] "numeric"
> mode(NULL)
[1] "NULL"
```

Es decir `is.numeric()` verifica que el tipo de dato almacenado sea "numeric" y ciertamente "NULL" no lo es.

Comment: La única frase que no entendí del todo es:
nos entrega un vector de lógicos consistente con la **longitud del vector de entrada**

Comment: Que la longitud del vector de salida va a ser igual al del vector de entrada `x <- c(1, NULL); length(x) == length(is.na(x))`

Comment: Ahora lo entendí mejor, ¡muchas gracias! Por último, ¿por qué se devuelve logical(0) al realizar la comparación NULL == 8? ¿Tiene que ver con la versión de R?

Comment: Por que la definición de la comparación dice que el retorno siempre es un vector de lógicos, en el caso particular que participe NULL, es un vector de lógicos de longitud 0.

Answer (score 3):

La función `is.na()` devuelve un valor `true` o `false` dependiendo del contenido. Sin embargo, al tener el valor `NULL`, el cual representa un objeto nulo en R y se usa principalmente para representar las listas con **longitud 0**, devolverá `logical(0)`.

`logical(0)` indica que tienes un vector que se supone que contiene valores booleanos, pero el vector tiene **longitud 0**. Esto se debe, como acabo de comentar, debido a `NULL`.

Comment: Sin embargo, cuando probamos is.numeric(NULL) devuelve FALSE

Comment: Claro, porque NULL no es un valor numérico. Es vacío, es nada, y no es igual a 0.

Comment: Entiendo lo que quieres decir, pero creo que R no resuelve de forma correcta este conflicto. Por ejemplo, is.na(NULL) devuelve logical(0), is.null(NA) devuelve FALSE, is.numeric(NULL) devuelve FALSE, NULL == 5 devuelve logical(0)